# How to make google Chrome omnibar search sites permanent?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

In google Chrome, when you have visited a site, say wikipedia.com, your can thereafter search the site directly from the omnibar by typing in a few letters then hitting `tab`.  However, I noticed that after I clear my cache, Chrome does not remember the search autofills, and I once again have to visit the site manually for it to take effect.

Is there a way to make the omnibar searches permanent even after doing a full cache clear in google Chrome?  Thanks.

**Update:** I tried the suggestion below, but bookmarking the site just allowed me to autocomplete the address.  It did *not* allow me the option to hit `tab` to do the search directly in the omnibar.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In future, if you have a specific issue to address with an answer, leave a comment on said answer instead of having to edit your question. Question edits are for clarifications and not really cluttered with why each answer doesn't quite work.

Comment: Unticking 'Clear saved form data' when you clear your cache and history may prevent your searches from being erased.

Comment: @random I am confused. Is not the information about what was tried and did *not* work a clarification of the question? It seems to be entirely consistent with what is suggested in [*this section of the faq*](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: "suggestion below" is very ambiguous and does not allow the answerer to know their question is short unless they're watching edits on the question @irr

Answer (score 1):

You can assign keywords for search-engines:

1. open the "Options" menu
2. "Basics" tab
3. under "Default Search" click the "Manage" button

In the popup window double-click any of the saved search-engines and assign a keyword (like 'a' for amazon etc.). To search just type 'keyword search-term' in the address bar and hit enter.

- I just assume that keyword searches are persistent, but didn't try it out actually
- the manage search engines popup is populated with search engines you already used, so if something is missing, just do a manual search first

Answer (score -1):

The Chrome address bar looks through your bookmarks, so:

1. Bookmark the site
2. Set up bookmark syncing

This saves your bookmarks in your Google Account and means that you'll always have access to them.